# Running an FQL query while parsing a Graph API result gives arrayindexoutofbound exception

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

After making a call to the "me/home" Graph API, while parsing the JSON result, I am trying to make another query using FQL. The FQL query problem was solved in my earlier question.

The background of my implementation is: I am using a `BaseAdapter` and from the main activity, I am sending the data parsed from `JSON` using multiple `ArrayLists`. If I am not making the FQL query, everything is peachy. But when I introduce the FQL query, the query is always run after the `adapter` has been set to the `ListView`. This keeps causing the arrayindexoutofbound exception.

This is the code that I am using including the additional FQL query while parsing the JSON result. To keep the code short, I will include the relevant part as the rest works just fine. If more is needed, however, I will put that up too.

```
// GET THE POST'S LIKES COUNT
if (json_data.has("likes")) {
    JSONObject feedLikes = json_data.optJSONObject("likes");
    String countLikes = feedLikes.getString("count");
    postLikesCountArrayList.add(countLikes);

    // TEST STARTS
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        graph_or_fql = "fql";
        String query = "SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = \'" 
        + finalThreadID + "\'";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("method", "fql.query");
        params.putString("query", query);
        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new LikesListener());
        }
    };
    TestNewsFeeds.this.runOnUiThread(run);                      
    // TEST ENDS
} else {
    String countLikes = "0";
    postLikesCountArrayList.add(countLikes);
}
```

And this is the code for the `LikesListener` class. It is a private class declared in the same activity:

```
private class LikesListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
//          Log.e("response", response);

            try {

                JSONArray JALikes = new JSONArray(response);
//              Log.v("JALikes", JALikes.toString());

                for (int j = 0; j < JALikes.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject JOTemp = JALikes.getJSONObject(j);
//                  Log.e("JOTemp", JOTemp.toString());

                    if (JOTemp.has("likes"))    {

                        JSONObject optJson = JOTemp.optJSONObject("likes");
//                      Log.v("optJson", optJson.toString());

                        if (optJson.has("user_likes"))  {
                            String getUserLikeStatus = optJson.getString("user_likes");
                            Log.e("getUserLikeStatus", getUserLikeStatus);
                            arrayLikeStatus.add(getUserLikeStatus);
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have figured out using debugging that the cause of the crash is the setAdapter being called before the second query completes. I see the log's being added to logcat after the crash has occured.

Any help on a solution for this is appreciated

**UPDATE**: Figured out the solution almost when I was about to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

So instead of calling the BaseRequestListener as used in the question, this modification had to be made.

```
try {
    graph_or_fql = "fql";
    String query = "SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = \'"
            + finalThreadID + "\'";
//                          Log.d("finalThreadID", finalThreadID);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
//                          Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, new LikesListener());

    String fqlResponse = Utility.mFacebook.request(params);
//                          Log.e("fqlResponse", fqlResponse);

    JSONArray JALikes = new JSONArray(fqlResponse);
//                          Log.v("JALikes", JALikes.toString());

    for (int j = 0; j < JALikes.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject JOTemp = JALikes.getJSONObject(j);
//                              Log.e("JOTemp", JOTemp.toString());

        if (JOTemp.has("likes"))    {
            JSONObject optJson = JOTemp.optJSONObject("likes");
//                                  Log.v("optJson", optJson.toString());

            if (optJson.has("user_likes"))  {
                String getUserLikeStatus = optJson.getString("user_likes");
//                                      Log.e("getUserLikeStatus", getUserLikeStatus);
                arrayLikeStatus.add(getUserLikeStatus);
//                                      Log.d("arrayLikeStatus", arrayLikeStatus.toString());
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Hope this helps someone save time if they are stuck like I was.